# Angular + Firebase Persistance of token

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication

I want to make the user logg in persistance (when he closes the page, he should not need to logg in again. From the documentation, I am doing as following:

```
signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
        .then(function() {
            return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(
                    response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        this.router.navigate(['/']);
                    }
                );
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
        });
}
```

But I am not navigating. Strangely, I injected the router:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

and it tells me:

```
[ts] Property 'router' is declared but its value is never read.
```

And I am clearly using it. Somehow, I can not get into the promise of signInWithEmailAndPassword.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the first then call (the one after ...Persistence.LOCAL) you have a function declaration. Unlike arrow functions, it will not keep the current context so when you use `this.router`, ***this*** will be the context of the above defined function.

So the warning is correct, you are not using the router defined on the class, you're using an undefined router property on the functions context. You probably don't see any error because there is no catch on the inner then.

The quickest way to fix this would be to use arrow functions in all the places, something like:

```
signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
        .then(() => firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(
                    response => {
...
```

You can look for more info about [this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).